# Semantics of Containers, which is used to deploy service-units, are not clear

Tags: juju

If we have a look at the status of a Juju environment we can see a set of machines and services. Within the services we can see a set of service-units.

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.1.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.1.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.154
    instance-id: atech-local-machine-1
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=i386

services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-3
    exposed: true
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.18.1.1
        machine: "1"
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: 10.0.3.154
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-46
    exposed: true
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "4"
```

But https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-constraints says, there is a constraint called "container", which specify the container type that a service-unit must run inside. But the above status log does not show any container related details.

On the other hand, in https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-subordinate-services, it says "Service units are typically run in an isolated container on a machine with no knowledge or access to other services deployed onto the same machine".

Does this mean, when we creating new service-units, does Juju runtime create a new container within a existing machine and deploy the service-unit? or create a new container within a new machine and deploy the service-unit? or use a single container to deploy all the service units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways Juju can deploy a unit to a machine but by default it will deploy the unit onto the bare metal of a new instance. Depending on how you specify your deploy command Juju can deploy it:

- onto the bare metal of the machine.
- into a lxc container on the machine.
- into a kvm container on the machine.
- and on and on...

Specifically if you are looking for more information on deploying services into containers you should take a look at the docs here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying#deploying-to-specific-machines-and-containers looking for the lines:

```
juju deploy mysql --to 24/lxc/3
juju deploy mysql --to lxc:25
```